# INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY with Webhook Guest Users and Managed Packages

Tags: managed-package, error-messages

*Adding this to the body of knowledge*

**Use case:**

1. Existing org with 100% successful regression tests
2. Existing transaction of webhook that creates `Account` + `Opportunity`, then updates the `Account`. Works fine; regression test with `runAs(theGuestuser)` works fine.
3. Add managed package to org (in this case, a Netsuite connector - Actian)
4. Rerun regression tests.

RESULT: Regression test fails with `INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY`

ERROR stacktrace identifies a trigger within the package that upserts managed package detail records in a master-detail to `Account`.

Answer (score 2):

**Succinct reason:**

- When running as guest user
- Creating or changing the owner on an object,
- Continuing in the transaction to a `with sharing` class that attempts to access the object.

**tl;dr**

> The reason for the specific error is as follows
>
> **Starting conditions**
>
> - Private OWD on Account
> - Force.com Managed Sharing (i.e. criteria-based sharing rules) extend R/W access on Account to other users based on Account record type
>
> **Transaction starts**
>
> 1. Webhook Sites guest user -- Apex Running user is guest user
> 2. `Account` created by Apex; owner is Guest User
> 3. Managed package trigger invoked; `PKG__detail__c` records upserted
> 4. `Opportunity` created by Apex; complex logic to assign `Opportunity.OwnerId` to something other than running user.
> 5. More complex logic ensues, eventually, `Account.OwnerId` is updated with the `Opportunity.OwnerId` *this is the root cause*
> 6. Managed package reinvokes its trigger to upsert the `PKG__detail__c` records (again)
> 7. `INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY` - presumably the `Account` as there are no other lookups or master relationships on the
>      `PKG__detail__c` SObject.
>
> **Underneath the covers and why the error occurs**
>
> 1. Guest users are not permitted to have View All or Modify All permissions on standard objects (e.g. `Account`)
> 2. Apex testmethods don't honor criteria-based sharing
> 3. The org's Apex code for this transaction was written with classes `without sharing` (and, in this use case, executed as a queueable)
>
> *HOWEVER...*
>
> 1. The managed package code runs `with sharing`
> 2. So, when the org code changed the owner on the Account to a non-guest user (see step 5 above)
> 3. The managed package code that upserted a `PKG__detail__c` object of `Account` failed because the (master) `Account` was no longer owned
>      by the running (guest) user and was in fact owned by a user the guest
>      user did not have access to (no View All, no criteria-based-sharing).
>
> **How might one get around this?**
>
> **Option 1** - Defer the ownership change on Account to a Platform Event trigger/Process Builder subscriber. These runAs `Automated
>   Process` and thus can access any object
>
> **Option 2** - Redesign the webhook to stash the incoming Json into an SObject, then execute a scheduled job that looks every 5 minutes for
>   stashed Json and performs all of the webhook logic. The scheduled job
>   runAs would be some user with broad privileges (esp View All on
>   Account in this use case)
>
> I believe Option 2 is better for:
>
> - If you are willing to burn a SFDC seat, you get perfect traceability in the createdBy/lastModifiedBy fields on the various SObjects DML'd
> - Option 1 is a one-off solution for this particular managed package interaction with org settings/org code. The next managed package might
>     not be so easy to workaround.
> - Option 1 could have bad consequences for automated emails that depend on a correct value for Account.Owner. More rework could be
>     required to prevent these from going out until the ownership was
>     finalized.
> - You do, however, introduce 5 minute latency to your webhook incoming receipt/transaction logic